# C program stuck on terminal when redirecting its output to another file from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to run a C program from a bash file in Linux and then write its output to another file (which is in another directory). The command I am using is:

```
gcc myfile.c -o test 
./test > /home/"$user"/Documents/"$name"/"$file"
```

Whenever I try to run this command, the program doesn't run, rather it is stuck on loading. Even if I write a single file name (from the same directory where the program is), the program does not run until I remove the whole redirection command and just write the simple ./test command. I don't know why this is occurring.

This is the C Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int array[100], n, c, d, swap;
  printf("Enter number of elements\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);
  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);
  for (c = 0 ; c < n - 1; c++)
  {
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (array[d] > array[d+1]) 
      {
        swap       = array[d];
        array[d]   = array[d+1];
        array[d+1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
     printf("%d\n", array[c]);
  return 0;
}
```

Even if I'm writing it like this:

```
./test | tee text.txt
```

It is not printing anything.

Comment: `the program doesn't run, rather it is stuck on loading` How do you check that? What is a "loading" state?

Comment: @KamilCuk that is waiting on an input rather than printing the contents of the program, and that input is not part of the program.

Comment: `that is waiting on an input rather than printing the contents of the program, and that input is not part of the program` How do you know that? You can't "observe" waiting. I suspect you only see that nothing is printed in your terminal and then in the other terminal you observe (with `ls`/`cat`) that the output file is empty, right? What should `./test` do? What should it print (what "contents of the program"?)? Can you post the content of `myfile.c`? Please post an [MCVE]. Would `stdbuf -oL ./test` fix the issue?

Comment: @KamilCuk I have not stated anywhere that the file is empty. I am just saying that if I remove the redirection command, the program works perfectly otherwise, it does not print anything, it does not give an error or anything, it is simply not working.

Comment: @alecxs Nothing.

Comment: @alecxs it is a sorting algorithm.

Comment: @alecxs Yes, I have initialized every variable.

Answer (score 2):

you can use command tee to collect printw info. like ./test | tee file
or you try to add 2>&1 in it.

Comment: do you use shell script?  i guess maybe your script has some error. please try it on terminal,observer whether it can run normally. I try it on my script. it runs normally. if could, please echo the path /home/"$user"/Documents/"$name"/"$file"

Comment: tried it on terminal, it is still not working. I don't know why.

Comment: if you use ./test > test.txt, how does it

Comment: i think whether your program is pause with code scanf("%d", &n) and waiting for input, so it will do not go on.

Comment: Any other way where I can store the values I've input and the output that is given based on those values into a text file?

Comment: i think you can store value in file and use fscanf to read them.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by using the `script` command in Linux. This command stores and writes both the input and the output that was provided during run-time of the C program into the desired text file. The `cat` and `tee` command doesn't work when there is `scanf` in the C program.